# Save file into external storage and open it

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a pdf file that is currently saved in internal storage.

I would like to either save this file to external storage and open it or open it directly from internal storage.

My code:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "HelloWorld.pdf");

document.Save(fileName);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: this has been discussed numerous times.  Have you tried searching?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I wouldn't ask otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher`. It enables an application to open a URI by the system. But it would not open a pdf file. You could open it by Word if your device have installed Microsoft Word app.

Refer to the MS docs for code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?tabs=ios#files

A easy way is to use a webview to display PDF.

Xaml:

```
<WebView WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" x:Name="MyWebview"></WebView>
```

Code behind:

```
  string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
     string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "a.pdf");
    MyWebview.Source = filePath;
```